# Xero API: by pass 1st time "login and select organisation" pop up

Tags: php, xero-api

Anyway Xero API OAuth 2.0 call can by pass or background handle the 1st time "Pop up ask for login and select organisation"? to allow more seamless/ silent API call?

Comment: You will have to use the popup to get your first access token. After that you can request a refresh token which will last for 30 days. You will have to request a new refresh token via the API within 30 days otherwise it will expire and require a new access token. So if all your users are using the same login and organisation it should just be a matter of storing your current request token somewhere.

Comment: @SharnWhite what would you recommend for storing the updated access token? Is it okay to be kept on server side cache? (Redis / Memached) ?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot bypass it, but you should only need to do this once and then you can programmatically refresh your tokens. You can follow this guide here -> https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/machine-2-machine

Comment: I was wondering about this myself and from the answers here there has to be initial human interaction to access the api. Isn't one of the main attributes of an api that it doesn't require human interaction to utilize? Seems like Xero dev is circumventing the entire idea of what an api is supposed to be.